# xcodebuild Interface Builder error, Failure Reason: Timed out waiting for FIFOs to open

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcodebuild, osx-elcapitan

I am getting an error when building with xcodebuild on Xcode 7.1/El Capitan

Restarting has not helped .

```
xcodebuild -workspace CL.xcworkspace -scheme CL -configuration Release


2015-11-12 11:55:49.889 ibtoold[5348:95303] [MT] DVTAssertions: 

Warning in
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-9059/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager.m:253

Details:  Failed to attach to Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool with error:
Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error
communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool."
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fda54ba7cc0 {Error
Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Failed to launch Interface Builder
Cocoa Touch Tool via CoreSimulator spawn"
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch
Tool via CoreSimulator spawn, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fda54b36cf0 {Error
Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Failed to handshake with platform
tool" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fda5510fed0 {Error
Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "" UserInfo=0x7fda550f1ad0 (not
displayed)}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to open connection over FIFOs with
platform tool, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to handshake with platform
tool}}}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with
Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check
Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for
further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch
Tool (5353) failed to launch}

Object:   

Method:
+_THREADSAFE_launchNewToolWithLaunchContext:executionContext:toolProxyClass:failureContext:requestingMethod:error:forReason:

Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}

Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and
any useful information you can provide.

2015-11-12 11:55:49.894 ibtoold[5348:95303] [MT] IBPlatformTool: *** Failed to
launch tool with description  System content 1x for
IBCocoaTouchFramework-NineOneAndLater w/ default fidelity: Encountered an error
communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. (Failure reason:
Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (5353) failed to launch): Failed to launch
Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool via CoreSimulator spawn: Failed to handshake
with platform tool (Failure reason: Failed to open connection over FIFOs with
platform tool): : Failed to open FIFOs for handshaking with platform tool
(Failure reason: Timed out waiting for FIFOs to open. Most likely Interface
Builder Cocoa Touch Tool crashed before it could open the other end.)

2015-11-12 11:56:01.366 ibtoold[5348:95303] [MT] IBPlatformTool: Wrote failed
marshalling request diagnostics to path:
/var/folders/57/r6trfqkx7m11pm6r1d276tbw0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2015-11-12_11-55-58_390000

/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */

/
/build/builds/CH_IOS_ChromeLync/AnyLync_Project/ConnectedHome/iOSClient/branches/ChromeLyncNew/CLLaunch
/Screen.xib: error: Internal error. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com and
/attach
/"/var/folders/57/r6trfqkx7m11pm6r1d276tbw0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2015-11-12_11-55-58_390000".

    Recovery Suggestion: Please check Console.app for crash reports for
    "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information.

    Underlying Errors:

        Description: Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder
        Cocoa Touch Tool.

        Failure Reason: Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (5353) failed to
        launch

        Recovery Suggestion: Please check Console.app for crash reports for
        "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information.

        Underlying Errors:

            Description: Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool via
            CoreSimulator spawn

            Underlying Errors:

                Description: Failed to handshake with platform tool

                Failure Reason: Failed to open connection over FIFOs with
                platform tool

                Underlying Errors:

                    Description:

                    Recovery Suggestion: Try restarting your computer

                    Underlying Errors:

                        Description: Failed to open FIFOs for handshaking with
                        platform tool

                        Failure Reason: Timed out waiting for FIFOs to open.
                        Most likely Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool crashed
                        before it could open the other end.
```

Comment: same here, it is boring....

Comment: Did you try deleting the derived data. Also, can you please go to all the xib files manually and see if it is loading the UI properly. Just a wild guess!

Comment: Try running this in Terminal as a non-sudo user : open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode. Hopefully you will see enough info about the error occurring. If you do please add it to the question.

Comment: Fortunately this seems to have resolved itself. Thanks for the responses , I will wait to see if I can get it to recocur

Comment: I had this same situation and this fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49459073/743608